# How to use separate assembly files with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, gcc, assembly

I have several .asm files with non-inline assembly, and if I include them in an Xcode project, there are very weird errors like comments not being interpreted as comments... Should I rename them or is there some other way to make them work under the Apple GCC?

Comment: GCC-based environments normally assume that assembly files to be run through the preprocessor (if only to remove comments) need a `*.S` name; can you try that ? In addition, please post the actual error messages you get.

Comment: Please post a build log excerpt that includes the commandline invocation intended to build a `.asm` file and the errors it produces, as well as the snippet of code generating the errors.

Comment: Changing file extension doesn't help... "; Assembly test" comments produce the No such instruction 'Assembly test' error. According to Apple Assembly guide the ; comments should be used for PPC and # comments should be used for Intel processerors... What the? My target arch is Intel and I really don't want to change all comments

Comment: You need to change all of your comments. For Intel assembly, the semicolon can be used to place multiple instructions on one line. You need to use either # or /* */.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what got recommended already. Rename your `.asm` files to `.s`.

After, check this tutorial about the internals: [Intel assembler on Mac OS X](http://orangejuiceliberationfront.com/intel-assembler-on-mac-os-x/).